# Power Automate: How to get the message ID to forward an email using 'Forward an email(V2)'?

Tags: power-automate, email-forwarding

I have been trying to automate the process of forwarding an email(with teams meeting link) using Power automate.

I have attached how my flow looks currently.

1. User submits the form with an email address
2. The flow retrieves the email address
3. Gets the events from the calendar
4. Filters to get a specific series
5. Forwards the email

I am struggling with steps 4 and 5 to get the specific message ID for the teams meeting.
I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know of a way.

[The overall flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUaeC.png)

The expanded 4th and 5th steps:
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzQ6k.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IpJ6.png)

I tried to just copy the meeting id you will get from the Microsoft teams calendar but it didn't work.
[image]

This is how my forward section looks like:

Answer (score 0):

The Second Filter Array under Apply to each 3 appears from this view to be filtering to the point there are no matches. Because that appears to be the email ID and not the meeting ID.  Have you considered using a Condition instead?  Then you can add the Meeting ID into the body of the email in your last step.

Comment: Apologies I seemed to have caused a confusion with the pictures. The flow end at apply each. The next filtering is the expansion of the flow to show what I did inside. I will look into the condition statement. Thanks.